# IF has 'Item Type' (Netsuite)

Tags: html, sql, freemarker, netsuite

I need a way to specify whether a certain sales order has ANY inventory items (if yes, this will display certain formatting information on PDF/HTML template)

I can't use suitescript or java or any type of coding on the Sales Order-side, so I need a way to do this by either using a custom field and/or coding on the PDF/HTML itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you don't need to count all the items and want to exit the loop as soon as you find the first Inventory Item, you could use `<#break>`:

```
<#assign hasInventoryItem = false>
<#list record.item as item>
  <#if item.itemtype == "InvtPart">
    <#assign hasInventoryItem = true>
    <#break>
  </#if>
</#list>

<#if hasInventoryItem == true>
  (your code here)
</#if>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<#assign numberInventoryItems = 0>
<#list record.item as item>
  <#if item.itemtype == "InvtPart">
    <#assign numberInventoryItems = numberInventoryItems + 1>
  </#if>
</#list>

<#if numberInventoryItems gt 0>
 (Your code here)
</#if>
```

Comment: Note that `<#assign numberInventoryItems = numberInventoryItems + 1>` can be written as `<#assign numberInventoryItems++>` (assuming you are using at least FreeMarker 2.3.23).

Comment: @ddekany Noted, though Netsuite provides version 2.3.19 I believe at the moment, so not an option at this stage.